# Vb.net how to put datagridview to report tablix. Datagrid view is not connected to database

Tags: vb.net

I fill a datagridview and iwant to print it on report viewer. Itried some q&a here but only the number of rows apear not the datas.

Comment: You don't. If you want a table of data in a report then the report provides ways to do that. You can use a `DataTable` as a data source for a report so you can create a `DataTable`, bind it to the `DataGridView`, have the user edit the data as required and then pass the `DataTable` to the report. Whether the `DataTable` is originally populated from a database isn't relevant to how you use it.

Comment: Ok im still a noob can you provide a link or sample on how to do that.

Comment: That's not what this site is for. I've told you what you need to do and now it's up to you to research how to do that and make an attempt to do it.  If you encounter a specific issue in that attempt, you then post a new question with all the information relevant to that issue. It's worth noting that there are multiple steps to what I suggested so you should be investigating each step separately. For instance, populating a `DataTable` has nothing to do with reports or `DataGridViews`, so that's a completely independent topic. Binding a `DataTable` to a `DataGridView` is another topic. Etc.